# Centralized sources of *monthly* data accessible through API (or otherwise automated query)

Tags: api

For teaching purposes (options for a class project), I am looking for sources of *monthly* data that can be programmatically accessed and downloaded into a high-level language (say `R` or `python`).

I am interested in any topic, ranging from geophysical to socio-economical all the way to financial, although I am particularly interested in socio-economical sources.

Ideally, the data should be as centralized and as global as possible. By that, I mean that I would prefer a single (or a few) stable sources providing access to a variety of data from all over the world than a long list of "smaller" providers each giving access to smaller and more local amounts of monthly data (e.g., one gateway for monthly climate data all over the world rather than a long list of individual weather stations each with their own API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quandl](https://www.quandl.com) (economics and finance), [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/) (economics), and [UN Data](http://data.un.org/) (especially their [MBS=Monthly Bulletin of Statistics Online site](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/mbs/app/DataSearchTable.aspx)) are all excellent places to start.