# Census CPS monthly API?

Tags: api, us-census

Related to this other question: [Centralized sources of *monthly* data accessible through API (or otherwise automated query)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/17948/centralized-sources-of-monthly-data-accessible-through-api-or-otherwise-autom)

Looking at https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets.html, it seemed to me that the Census bureau does not yet have an API for monthly CPS data. In R, I couldn't find an api listed under `listCensusApis()` from `censusapi` , which reinforced my impression that there just wasn't an API for this data.

So I went through the ordeal of manually selecting variables using the data browser: https://data.census.gov/mdat.

Once I was done, I ended up on the final download page. To my surprise, on top of a direct dowload link, that page also included two API links:

[image]

[image]

So **my questions are**:

- Is there or is there not an API for that data?
- If there is, what are its name, query structure, etc.?
- In particular, can I query it using `getCensus` from `censusapi`, and if so, how (what are the `name` and `vintage` format and can I obtain summary statistics by state or otherwise select a custom geography?)